# Hybris custom email setting custom attributes

Tags: java, email, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm creating a custom email, which should be sent to the customer after filling the form for making an appointment. I needed additional attributes, so I've extended `AbstractEmailContext`:

```
public class AppointmentEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext
{
   private String myAttribute;
   ...
}
```

I'm setting the attributes in my EventListener before I'm starting the process:

```
final AppointmentProcessModel storeFrontCustomerProcessModel = (AppointmentProcessModel) getBusinessProcessService()
                .createProcess(
                        "appointmentEmailProcess-" + event.getEmail() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        "appointmentEmailProcess");

storeFrontCustomerProcessModel.setMyAttribute("test@test.com");
getModelService().save(storeFrontCustomerProcessModel);
getBusinessProcessService().startProcess(storeFrontCustomerProcessModel);
```

In the `init` method of the `AppointmentEmailContext` I can't get those parameters so I could set them properly and pass them to the email template. The other thing is, the entering ProcessModel in `init` method isn't instance of `AppointmentProcessModel`, but it's the instance of `StoreFrontCustomerProcessModel`, even though my `AppointmentProcessModel` is extending it.

I also tried to add `AppointmentProcessModel` like this:

```
public class AppointmentEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext<AppointmentProcessModel>
{
...
}
```

and adjust init method with correct parameters (+ add overriding methods), but then I got error while creating the process:

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP21] [HybrisApplicationEventMulticaster] java.lang.InstantiationException: mypackage.core.appointment.model.AppointmentProcessModel
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: mypackage.core.appointment.model.AppointmentProcessModel
```

I don't know if there is a problem with persisting those attributes, or if I should pass those attributes some other way.

UPDATE:
I tried to add the `AppointmentProcess` to the `*-items.xml` file and I did the system update, but no changes. I checked in the **backoffice** that the type is added and it is extending from `StoreFrontCustomerProcess`. The definition is as follows:

```
        <itemtype code="AppointmentProcess" extends="StoreFrontCustomerProcess"
                  autocreate="true" generate="true"
                  jaloclass="mypackage.jalo.AppointmentProcess">
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="email" type="java.lang.String">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

Comment: Try `public class AppointmentEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext<AppointmentProcessModel>` and your *init* method will be like `@Override
 public void init(final AppointmentProcessModel appointmentProcessModel, final EmailPageModel emailPageModel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross verify through HMC, whether your attribute gets saved in storeFrontCustomerProcessModel or not?

Try changing **AppointmentEmailContext** class like

```
public class AppointmentEmailContext extends AbstractEmailContext<AppointmentProcessModel>
{
   private String myAttribute;

    @Override
    public void init(final AppointmentProcessModel appointmentProcessModel, final EmailPageModel emailPageModel)
    {
        super.init(appointmentProcessModel, emailPageModel);
        myAttribute = appointmentProcessModel.getMyAttribute();
    }

    public String getMyAttribute() {
        return myAttribute;
    }

    //...
}
```

---

**Edit**

A user hasn't created the Item type for `AppointmentProcess`, later he has created it as I mentioned in the comment and issue resolved!!

Comment: I also tried that, but then I got error while instantiating the process, see the edited question, thanks.

Comment: And yes, the process is saved in the backoffice, but I can't see/find `myAttribute` there. I tried again to add `AppointmentProcessModel`, the process is triggered, but then it fails again while executing with: `StoreFrontCustomerProcessModel cannot be cast to mypackage.core.appointment.model.AppointmentProcessModel`. Note, that it is still extending it.

Comment: I tried that now, no change. Also I'm seeing this error in log:
`ERROR [hybrisHTTP15] [CascadingModelWalker] Model AppointmentProcessModel (<unsaved>) has got unknown unlocalized dirty attribute myAttribute. Most likely the code base had been changed without system update ! (ignoring attribute)`

Comment: Do I need to register `AppointmentProcessModel` as new `itemType` in my `*-items.xml` file?

Comment: Make sure you extends StoreFrontCustomerProcess while declaring your AppointmentProcess in *items.xml and then update system with option "update running system"

Comment: I added it as you mentioned, I did the update, still no changes. See updated question. I also had to remove the jalo class I wrote manually, since the `AppointmentProcess` class is generating itself.

Comment: Note the difference between `AppointmentProcessModel` and `AppointmentProcess` (which I added there). I don't have `AppointmentProcessModel` in the `items.xml`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179832/discussion-between-hybrishelp-and-stepan-tuhacek).